How to write a C++20 function accepting a range with both T and const T?
I defined the following function:
template<
    std::ranges::contiguous_range R,
    typename T = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>
>
std::span<T> foo(R&& r, const T& someValue) {
    std::span<T> sp{r.begin(), r.end()};
    /// ...
    return sp;
}

Now I have three use cases:
std::vector<std::string> baseVec;
auto a = foo(baseVec, {""});

std::span<std::string> sp{baseVec};
auto b = foo(sp, {""});

const std::vector<std::string>& ref = baseVec;
auto c = foo(ref, {""}); // <------------------ problem here!

As far as I could understand, foo(ref) will fail to compile because the span created inside foo is of type span<T>, whereas in this case it should be span<const T>.
So, how can I write foo so it accepts all the three cases?

The issue is that the value_type of a range is never const-qualified. But reference type of the range could be - although there that's still wrong because it'd be string const&.
Contiguous iterators are required to have their reference type to be U& for some type U, so if we simply drop the trailing reference we'll get a potentially const-qualified type:
template<
    std::ranges::contiguous_range R,
    typename T = std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>
>
std::span<T> foo(R&& r, const T& someValue) {
    std::span<T> sp(r);
    /// ...
    return sp;
}

Note that you don't need to pass r.begin() and r.end() into span, span has a range constructor.
However, this still isn't quite correct for a reason that the original was also wrong. contiguous is an insufficient criteria here, we also need the range to be sized so that we can construct a span out of it:
template<
    std::ranges::contiguous_range R,
    typename T = std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>
>
    requires std::ranges::sized_range<R>
std::span<T> foo(R&& r, const T& someValue) {
    std::span<T> sp(r);
    /// ...
    return sp;
}

Also you probably don't want to deduce T from the argument - you really want it to be specifically the correct T associated with the range:
template<
    std::ranges::contiguous_range R,
    typename T = std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>
>
    requires std::ranges::sized_range<R>
std::span<T> foo(R&& r, std::type_identity_t<T> const& someValue) {
    std::span<T> sp(r);
    /// ...
    return sp;
}


Note that I changed your code to construct the span using parentheses instead of braces. This is because passing an iterator pair into an initializer using braces is not a good idea, because it could easily do the wrong thing. Consider:
auto x = std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4};

auto a = std::vector(x.begin(), x.end()); // four ints: [1, 2, 3, 4]
auto b = std::vector{x.begin(), x.end()}; // two iterators: [x.begin(), x.end()]

And the same is true for span, which will have an initializer_list constructor starting in C++26.

Kind of an odd last section, since the final version doesn't even pass a pair of iterators at all. Presumably the range c'tor and the initializer_list c'tor would be properly constrained to not step on each other's toes, so the range could be passed with braces or parentheses.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I do not think it's ever odd to point out bad practices.

I don't disagree, but the initial section has a nice thematic flow that is very clear and informative. Whereas the second one just doesn't fit all that well with it, even as an addendum. It reads more like a random afterthought. An edit to tie them up more would make it stick out less (and improve the general flow of the answer).

Hum, how does the std::type_identity_t part work, any practical examples?

OT, but I can not keep myself. Getting span to construct from initializer_list is an awkward move. I was hoping to see initializer_list deprecated. span<const T> could simply be the replacement.

You can go the proverbial route. If the compiler is so clever, let it figure out the type on its own. With class template argument deduction, it's possible.
template<
    std::ranges::contiguous_range R,
    typename T = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>
>
auto foo(R&& r, const T&) {
    std::span sp (r.begin(), r.end()); // CTAD + auto return type
    /// ...
    return sp;
}

